# Inner AlertDialog calls REST url, How do I wait for return with Progress Dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

I have a series of AlertDialogs that are daisy-chained inside of the onclick methods.  On the last one I need to send a call to URL and wait for the response.  Once the response comes back I need to take the message of the response and create the last AlertDialog.  Problem is this works in 2.3 Android but with the latest changes to Android 4.0 error out because the REST http call runs on the UI thread.  So I want to move this to an AsyncTask.  I read through the tutorials but haven't found my specific dilemma.  Here is my code:  How do I make the AlertDialog wait for a response and also while it is waiting show a ProgressDialog or Spinner?  I am looking for something elegant where the AsyncTask is a generic call and can be used in other situations for REST calls.

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
        break;
    }

    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingTitle1).toString())
    .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingMessage1).toString())
    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingPositive1).toString(),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (onClicked) {
                log.info("Preventing multiple clicks to Ping Node Id");
                return;
            }

            onClicked = true;
            String returnMessage = "";
            int iconId = 0;
            try {
                String url = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.urlIdPing).toString(), getRestUrl(), getId() );

                // This is where the Rest call will happen in an AsyncTask
                AsyncRest rest = new AsyncRest( Preferences.this );
                rest.execute( new RestObject(type,null,null,true,false) );

            ..........................

                // This is the current state of the 2.3 code
                JSONObject sent = RestRequest.sendPost(RestHttp.createHttpClient(), url, null, true);
                if (sent != null && sent.getInt("response") == 200) {
                    returnMessage = "VALID REST call ";
                    iconId = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info;
                } else {
                    if (sent != null) {
                        returnMessage = "INVALID REST response " + "\n\n Response code: " + sent.getInt("response");
                    } else {
                        returnMessage = "INVALID REST call.";
                    }
                    iconId = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
                }
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                returnMessage = "Errored in JSON payload.";
            }

            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SetPreferences.this)
            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingTitle2).toString())
            .setMessage(returnMessage)
            .setIcon(iconId)
            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alertOkay).toString(), 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
            }).show();

        }
    })
}).show();

onClicked = false;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really specify exactly what the problem is, but I'm assuming it's that you're not sure how to implement an `AsyncTask`.

Take a look at the developer docs for `AsyncTask`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

There's an example that you can follow there.  Basically, you want to have your REST call inside `doInBackground()` of the AsyncTask.  Then any changes to the UI that you need after the call finishes would go in `onPostExecute()`.

**EDIT:** more detail

```
 private class AsyncRest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
  protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
     // do your REST call here
     return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing) {
     // update your UI here
  }
 }
```

To execute, call `new AsyncRest().execute(url);`

To get the results of the background tasks make the get() call after the execute.

```
AsyncRest rest = new AsyncRest( SetPreferences.this );
rest.execute( new RestObject(Constants.ROTypes.post,url,null,null,true,false) );
JSONObject sent = rest.get();
```

Comment: Edited question to ask a more specific one.  I am already using AysyncTasks just not sure how to make the alert wait for the AsyncTask to produce a callback since the alerts are embedded and inside the onClick method of the Activity.  I can post my AsyncTask too if needed.

Comment: Signal the alert to close or whatever you need it to do in `onPostExecute`

Comment: I know all this already but what I don't know is how to make the alert wait at the point in code when async is fired as I am sure it doesn't pause the UI thread.

Comment: Put all of the code that you want to execute after the alert "waits" in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: So the whole GUI thread pauses in the onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask, cool then this should work.

Comment: Second part is how do I popup a spinner to let the user know something is happening.  Wish they had a better way to do this in Android or was a default behavior for AsyncTasks

Comment: The only way to do this would be to use a custom XML layout for your dialog with the spinner in it.  Then, in `onPreExecute` of the `AsyncTask`, make it visible, and in `onPostExecute` hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `AsyncTask` your code would look something like this:

In your activity...

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements AsyncRestCallback {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
            break;
        }

        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingTitle1).toString())
        .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingMessage1).toString())
        .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingPositive1).toString(),
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (onClicked) {
                    log.info("Preventing multiple clicks to Ping Node Id");
                    return;
                }

                onClicked = true;
                String returnMessage = "";
                int iconId = 0;
                String url = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.urlIdPing).toString(), getRestUrl(), getId() );

                AsyncRest rest = new AsyncRest().execute( url );
            })
    }).show();

    onClicked = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void finished(String returnMessage) {

        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SetPreferences.this)
        .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.alertPingTitle2).toString())
        .setMessage(returnMessage)
        .setIcon(iconId)
        .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alertOkay).toString(), 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
        }).show();
    }
}
```

RestAsync

```
public class AsyncRest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private AsyncRestCallback callback;

    public AsyncRest(AsyncRestCallback callback) {

        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String returnMessage = "";
        String url = params[0]

        try {

            JSONObject sent = RestRequest.sendPost(RestHttp.createHttpClient(), url, null, true);
            if (sent != null && sent.getInt("response") == 200) {
                returnMessage = "VALID REST call ";
                iconId = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info;
            } 
            else {
                if (sent != null) {
                    returnMessage = "INVALID REST response " + "\n\n Response code: " + sent.getInt("response");
                } 
                else {
                    returnMessage = "INVALID REST call.";
                }
                iconId = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
            }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            returnMessage = "Errored in JSON payload.";
        }

        return returnMessage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String returnMessage) {

        callback.finished(returnMessage);
    }

    public interface AsyncRestCallback {

        public void finished(String returnMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh that is ugly, issue with this is that I am trying to make a generic Async class not one specific to this one task, I have 10 others similar but may or may not include alerts and all with different icons and titles.

Comment: If you want to make a generic one, you can just put an `interface` in your `AsyncTask` class that is called when it is finished.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect this implementation.